# SQL - Table Join To Compare NULL Values Where Join is NULL

Tags: sql

I've been asked to basically write a report that displays data in two different databases and be able to see in either database if something is missing.

IE, the invoice number may exist in database1, but not in database2 and vice versa.

I've got the following query below but it only returns all the data from the second table, with NULL values for the first. I'd like to set it up to return the NULL Values in both, but I think the problem is because my join is on the values that can be NULL, so it won't return the values that exist in the first table and not the second.

Can someone step me through how to resolve an issue like this?

As far as I'm aware, I don't necessarily have any other tables to join unless I try to join more tables from each database.
Query:

```
Select TC.PO_Number, TC.Invoice_Date, TC.Invoice_, H.RefPoNum, H.InvoiceNum 
From Table1 TC
RIGHT JOIN [SERVERNAME].[DBNAME].[TABLE2] H ON (TC.Invoice_ = H.InvoiceNum)
Where TC.Invoice_Date Between '2018-10-31' AND '2018-10-31' 
AND H.Company Like 'COMPANY'
```

Comment: You need two queries: one to find the null values in table1, and the other to find the null values in table2.

Comment: What database software are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with a `full join`.  Filtering is tricky with a `full join`, so I recommend subqueries:

```
select tc.PO_Number, tc.Invoice_Date, tc.Invoice_, h.RefPoNum, h.InvoiceNum 
From (select tc.*
      from Table1 tc
      where tc.Invoice_Date Between '2018-10-31' AND '2018-10-31'
     ) tc full join
     (select h.*
      from [SERVERNAME].[DBNAME].[TABLE2] h
      where h.Company Like 'COMPANY'
     ) h
     on TC.Invoice_ = H.InvoiceNum;
```

Comment: this seems to work as far as running, but i immediately run into an issue where it only returned one result, but looking into the data, the invoice date fields were off by a month of so.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the column you are comparing has the same data type and you can safely use this query below:

Server01 NOT IN Server02

```
select t1.InvoiceNumber from server01.dbo.Invoice t1
except
select t2.InvoiceNumber from server02.dbo.Invoice t2
```

Server02 NOT IN Server01

```
select t1.InvoiceNumber from server02.dbo.Invoice t1
except
select t2.InvoiceNumber from server01.dbo.Invoice t2
```

P.S.
While this may not be the exact query you are looking for, but this template may help.